# Custom Zend_Form element disappearing after validation

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I've created a custom form element that allows me to place text in an arbitrary location in my form:

```
<?php 

class Plano_Form_Element_Note extends Zend_Form_Element_Xhtml
{
    public $helper = 'formNote';

    /**
     * Default decorators
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function loadDefaultDecorators()
    {
        if ($this->loadDefaultDecoratorsIsDisabled()) {
            return;
        }

        $decorators = $this->getDecorators();
        if (empty($decorators)) {
            $this->addDecorator('ViewHelper')
                 ->addDecorator('Errors')
                 ->addDecorator('Label')
                 ->addDecorator(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'form-row clearfix'));
        }
    }       
}
```

**This works like a charm, but as soon as I hit $form->isValid() the element turns up empty and only the wrapper shows**:

```
<div class="form-row clearfix"></div>
```

The elements are added using subforms (method in my form class below):

```
/**
 * Setup form elements and generate subforms
 *  
 * @return Event_Form_Feedback_Enter
 */
protected function setupForm()
{
    $partMapper = new Event_Model_FeedbackPart_Mapper();
    $parts = $partMapper->fetchByFeedbackId($this->getFeedback()->getId(), array('order ASC', 'id DESC'));
    foreach ($parts as $part)
    {
        switch ($part->getType())
        {
            case Event_Model_FeedbackPart::TYPE_TEXT:
                $subform = new Event_Form_Feedback_Enter_Text();
                break;
            case Event_Model_FeedbackPart::TYPE_QUESTION_OPEN:
                $subform = new Event_Form_Feedback_Enter_Question();
                break;
            case Event_Model_FeedbackPart::TYPE_QUESTION_MC:
                $subform = new Event_Form_Feedback_Enter_MultipleChoiceQuestion();
                break;
        }

        $subform->setup($part);
        $this->addSubForm($subform, 'part-' . $part->getId());
    }

    $this->addSubmit();
}
```

... and here is the element creation in the actual form class (`Event_Form_Feedback_Enter_Text`):

```
protected function setupForm()
{
    $element = new Plano_Form_Element_Note('description');
    $element->setValue($this->getPart()->getDescription());
    $this->addElement($element);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the validation was breaking for static form element. To solve this, I have overridden the isValid() method in my `Plano_Form_Element_Note` class:

```
public function isValid($value)
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach for placing arbitrary static content into a form is the [AnyMarkup decorator](http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/62).